# Listar arquivos do diretório e subdiretório com listFiles

Tags: java

Hoje eu listo através do código abaixo os arquivos que estão no diretório passado pelo parâmetro, porém agora eu gostaria de listar também os arquivos que estão nos subdiretórios. Fiz algumas buscas mas eu não achei nada que não altere muito minha estrutura, também achei que retirando o `isFile()` resolveria, mas não deu certo.

```
void indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(File raiz) {
    FilenameFilter filtro = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File arquivo, String nome) {
            return nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".odt")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".doc")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docx")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ppt")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pptx")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
                    || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".rtf");
        }
    };

    for (File arquivo : raiz.listFiles(filtro)) {
        if (arquivo.isFile()) {
            try {
                // Extrai o conteúdo do arquivo com o Tika;
                String textoExtraido = getTika().parseToString(arquivo);
                indexaArquivo(arquivo, textoExtraido);
                System.out.println(arquivo);
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        } else {
            indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(arquivo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora que eu respondi que eu li a restrição `com listFiles()`. Deve ser assim ou minha resposta atende? Se não for uma restrição, e for apenas uma sugestão, poderia alterar o título?

Comment: @Math eu queria com o listFiles() pois acho que fica mais enxuto. Mas obrigado de qualquer forma pela contribuição, vou dar uma olhada nem que seja para aprender.

Comment: Sem problemas, eu fui na empolgação por que eu já conhecia esse walkTreeFile(), rs.. Se eu tiver um tempo dou uma pesquisada nesse método que você falou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode percorrer uma estrutura de diretórios, subdiretórios e arquivos com o método:

```
Path walkFileTree(Path start, FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor)
```

Você precisa especificar o diretório inicial e implementar a interface FileVisitor para dizer exatamente quais informações que devem ser mostradas quando percorrer o diretório ou arquivo em questão.

Um exemplo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

class MyFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes){
        System.out.println("Nome do arquivo:" + path.getFileName());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes){
        System.out.println("----------Nome do diretório:" + path + "----------");
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}

public class Walk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path source = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Math\\Desktop");
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(source, new MyFileVisitor());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Fonte: [Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805: A Comprehensive OCPJP 7 Certification Guide (Expert's Voice in Java)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430247649)

Comment: Esse é mesmo o melhor jeito. E se quiser um exemplo de uma classe utilitária que localiza um arquivo nos subdiretórios, veja [esta aqui](https://github.com/utluiz/myq/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/myq/util/QueryLoaderUtil.java) (vá até o método `findFile`).

Comment: @utluiz poisé, a princípio pode parecer desnecessário e trabalhoso ter que implementar uma interface "apenas" para percorrer diretórios, mas acredito que seja o jeito mais limpo e mais fácil de desenvolver e dar manutenção. Obrigado pela sua contribuição!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver minha dificuldade da seguinte forma:
Como eu já estava usando um filtro para me mostrar o tipo de arquivos que eu estava interessado, cheguei a conclusão que o lugar certo para se verificar seria aí. Então me veio na cabeça que um diretório não possui extensão, então ele acabaria com "vazio" o nome, e foi o que eu fiz. Adicionei a linha `nome.toLowerCase().endsWith("")` no meu `FilenameFilter` e funcionou.

Ficou assim o código:

```
void indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(File raiz) {
        FilenameFilter filtro = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File arquivo, String nome) {
                return nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".odt")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".doc")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docx")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ppt")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pptx")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".rtf")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith("");
            }
        };

    for (File arquivo : raiz.listFiles(filtro)) {
        if (arquivo.isFile()) {
            try {
                // Extrai o conteúdo do arquivo com o Tika;
                String textoExtraido = getTika().parseToString(arquivo);
                indexaArquivo(arquivo, textoExtraido);
                System.out.println(arquivo);
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        } else {
            indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(arquivo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pessoas que tenham dificuldade semelhante, mas que possam utilizar versões mais recentes do Java, deveriam considerar o uso da classe Path (ver resposta postada por @Math) em lugar da classe File como recomendado em [Legacy File I/O Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html).