# Como pesquisar por .exe?

Tags: java

Como eu faço para que uma aplicação em Java que pesquise por um ".exe" dentro de uma pasta e dentro dessa pasta tem subpastas. Quero que ele procure para mim mesmo tendo subpastas. E retorna-se true ou false.

Por exemplo:

C:\Windows\ ai quero que acha cmd.exe
Embora eu sei que CMD.exe fique dentro do System32. Mais quero que ele procure dentro das subpastas do C:/Windows/

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Ja pensou em utilizar recursão para fazer isso?

Comment: O que você tentou? Qual a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Talvez isso aqui te ajude: [Listar arquivos do diretório e subdiretório com listFiles](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20930/3117)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar recursão para fazer isso, de uma olhada no código abaixo que retirei do site: http://www.mkyong.com/java/search-directories-recursively-for-file-in-java/

No exemplo, ele está procurando por **post.php** dentro de **/Users/mkyong/websites** e seus subdiretórios.

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileSearch {

  private String fileNameToSearch;
  private List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

  public String getFileNameToSearch() {
    return fileNameToSearch;
  }

  public void setFileNameToSearch(String fileNameToSearch) {
    this.fileNameToSearch = fileNameToSearch;
  }

  public List<String> getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();

        //try different directory and filename :)
    fileSearch.searchDirectory(new File("/Users/mkyong/websites"), "post.php");

    int count = fileSearch.getResult().size();
    if(count ==0){
        System.out.println("\nNo result found!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("\nFound " + count + " result!\n");
        for (String matched : fileSearch.getResult()){
        System.out.println("Found : " + matched);
        }
    }
  }

  public void searchDirectory(File directory, String fileNameToSearch) {

    setFileNameToSearch(fileNameToSearch);

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        search(directory);
    } else {
        System.out.println(directory.getAbsoluteFile() + " is not a directory!");
    }

  }

  private void search(File file) {

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      System.out.println("Searching directory ... " + file.getAbsoluteFile());

            //do you have permission to read this directory?    
        if (file.canRead()) {
        for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
            if (temp.isDirectory()) {
            search(temp);
            } else {
            if (getFileNameToSearch().equals(temp.getName().toLowerCase())) {           
                result.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
            }

        }
        }

     } else {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permission Denied");
     }
      }

      }

}
```

No caso mostrado pelo site, a saída foi a seguinte:

> ```
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/css
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/images
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/images/screenshots
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/includes
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/js
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/maint
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/network
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/user
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-content
> Searching directory ... /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-content/plugins
> //long list, omitted.
>
> Found 3 result!
>
> Found : /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/includes/post.php
> Found : /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-admin/post.php
> Found : /Users/mkyong/websites/wp-includes/post.php
> ```

Comment: Gostei diferente a pesquisa. Consegui alterar e fica do jeito que eu precisava. Obrigado